# Is it possible to extract an HTML code (for <table> to be ore specific) from mysql?

Tags: mysql, string, extract

I have an old, custom made website I have to move to WordPress. The "Featured image" of the current website is actually hardcoded at the very beginning of the content inside of the one-cell table.
The website has 73K+ records so to do it manually would take years. :)

I wonder if it's possible to extract the code, from "<table " to ""?

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Afan

Comment: Can you be more specific or provide an example? Maybe you can use substring()

Comment: The articles are something like this:
"<table bgcolor=black width=680 border=0 cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0 align=center><tr><td align=left><img src=http://www.example.com/photo/article_main_image.jpg border=0 width=680></td></tr></table>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur."

Comment: I figured out how to do it. I know it's not the correct nor the best solution, but it works :D

-- extract strings 150 char long, from 'article_content', that starts with 'http://www.example.net/photo/'
INSERT INTO article_featured_image_transition SELECT id, substring(article_content, locate('http://www.example.net/photo/', article_content), 250) FROM articles WHERE locate('http://www.example.net/photo/', article_content) > 0;

Comment: (continued)

-- Remove next line code (\n, \r, \n\r)
UPDATE article_featured_image_transition SET image_url = REPLACE(REPLACE(image_url, '\r', ''), '\n', '');

-- Remove everything after ".jpg". I put 500 length even the string is no longer than 250 chars
UPDATE article_featured_image_transition SET image_url = REPLACE(image_url, substring(image_url, (locate('.jpg', image_url) + 4), 500), '');